# $\kappa < \mathfrak{p}$ implies $MA_{\mathbb{P}}(\kappa)$ for $\mathbb{P}$ $\sigma$-centered

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of theorem III.3.61 in Kunen's Set-theory book (2013 edition), which focuses on showing

> If $\aleph_0\leq\kappa < \mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ is a $\sigma$-centered poset then $MA_{\mathbb{P}}(\kappa)$

I can follow the proof but I don't really get the entire picture. I'd appreciate some explanation as to what is going on there.

Comment: Can you please sketch Kunen's argument (I don't have access to Kunen's book, and I couldn't find the proof in the usual references)?

Comment: @Haim Well part of the problem is that I don't understand the proof well enough to sketch it properly... He says there the the proof follows the exposition of Blass an the Handbook of Set theory (Vol. I)